# Fetching data from Mongo based on ObjectID on logged in user

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I have two collections in my Mongo DB which looks like this:

**Documents**

User:

```
id: ObjectId ("5fb39e3d11eaad3e30cfb1b0")
userName: "Tobias"
password: "yyy"

id: ObjectId ("5fb3c83fb774ff3340482250")
userName: "Thor"
password: "xxx"
```

Courses:

```
id: ObjectId ("5fb3cf3da8227e101826e2db")
CourseName: "Design"
userId: "5fb39e3d11eaad3e30cfb1b0" (THIS IS THE SAME AS THE OBJECT ID FOR THE FIRST USER)
```

When a user is logging in, the user can add a course and the object ID for the logging in user will be added to the collection in MongoDB along with the coursename (just as in the example above).

My question is, how do I show only the courses which matches the user which are logged in? I'm using mongoose for user-login, express for server conn, ejs for view, and VueJS for control.

I'm comming from relationel databases, so not sure if the approch i'm trying out here with joining the objectID's is good practice.

Comment: in the mongodb world you usually try to embedd the data

Comment: read a bit more about mongoose.find() method.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql you join, in mongodb you use `$lookup`

```
   CoursesModel.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: UserModel.collection.name,
          localField: "userId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "user"
        }
      },
    ]).then(result => {
       console.log(result);
    })
```

In your result you will have an additional field called `user`. This will be an array with all documents that matched the userId

Instead of `UserModel.collection.name` you could use an string as name. But i prefer using the collection name programatically.

Comment: I cannot aggregrate userId to _Id because it's is ObjectId and the other one is just a string..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find()` or `findOne()` function.

```
courses.findOne(function (err, course) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  if (course) {
//do Something
  }
});
```